# Flutter BarCode to check if data contains Letters/Word with QR Code Scanner

Tags: flutter, null, invoke, flutter-qrcode

Hi I have been trying to read the QR Code and then navigate to a page when scan data contains specific keyword. Currently, I did print the data and it shows correctly, but when I want pass it to check with startsWith then it show the error below. I have tried using contains as well (Same Error), I did check the value is null before applying, and I also add  ? before initializing Barcode. The code is edited from the example of packages qr_code_scanner. The related code I feel like is only here. I am not sure what am I missing now to remove this error. Please help.

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((Barcode? scanData) {
      setState(() {
        Barcode? result;
        result = scanData;
        if (result != null){
          if(result!.code.startsWith("anything")){
            \\Navigate here
          }
        }
        
      });
    });
  }
```

I am getting error shown below from `result!.code.startsWith("anything")`

```
The method 'startsWith' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the condition like this

```dart
if(result !=null && result.code!=null){
   if (result!.code!.startsWith("anything")) {
       // do you navigation here
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for me, it seems that this can debug through visual studio code auto fix as well, I only noticed it after using your solutions. Thank you very much

Comment: yeah you can get quick solution in vs code by keyboard shortcut `ctrl+.`

Answer (score 0):

you should try updating if condition inside your method to the following:

```
if (result != null) {
    if (result.code?.startsWith("anything") ?? false) {
      // TODO: Add the navigation code
    }
  }
```